# Multiplying Numpy 3D arrays by 1D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, array-broadcasting

I am trying to multiply a 3D array by a 1D array, such that each 2D array along the 3rd (depth: d) dimension is calculated like:

`1D_array[d]*2D_array`

And I end up with an array that looks like, say:

```
[[
[1,1]
[1,1]]
[
[2,2]
[2,2]]
[
[3,3]
[3,3]]]
```

Which would be the result of correctly multiplying np.ones((3,2,2)) with [1,2,3].

I've been trying for some time now and whatever I seem to do I can't end up with this result, just variations on the theme. How do I correctly go about doing this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If your arrays are `a` and `b`, are you looking for `b[:, None] * a`?

Comment: I just tried `b=np.ones((3,2,2))`
`a=np.array(range(-1,2))`
`ans=b[:, None]*a`

But it threw an error: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,3) (3,2,2)` 

I'm sure I'm just doing something foolish?

Comment: in this case I think you want `a[:, None, None] * b`.

Comment: Thankyou, that appears to be exactly what I want!

Comment: You ask for "2D arrays stacked along the 3rd dimension", but your example has them stacked along the 1st dimension.

Comment: Good point Jaime, I made a mistake when I posed the question, so thankyou for the clarification.

Hopefully other users that find this post will still be able to work with Alok's replies.

Comment: @Alok, you could post your comment as an answer since it solved the problem...

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume `b=np.ones((3,2,2))` and `a=np.array([1,2,3])`. I really do like the answer of @Alok which uses the simple `a[:, None, None] * b` which surely works with your problem. What I dislike with this formulation is that it's quite dimension specific. What I mean is that it can only be used with 3 dimensional arrays, which was not true in my problem, where b could be a 1D or a 3D array with the exact same length for `axis 0`. I hence found a way to accommodate it to my problem :

```
broad_a = np.broadcast_to(a, b.T.shape).T
result = broad_a * b
print(result)
[[
[1,1]
[1,1]]
[
[2,2]
[2,2]]
[
[3,3]
[3,3]]]
```

Giving also the intended result for your case.